# Handling pointers when wrapping C++ class with Cython

Tags: python, c++, pointers, cython

I'm having trouble when handling pointers with cython. The cython implementation of the class holds a pointer to a C++ instance of class `Person`. Here's my `.pyx` file:

**person.pyx**

```
cdef class PyPerson:
    cdef Person *pointer

    def __cinit__(self):
        self.pointer=new Person()

    def set_parent(self, PyPerson father):
        cdef Person new_father=*(father.pointer)
        self.c_person.setParent(new_father)
```

The C++ method `setParent` takes a `Person` object as an argument. Since the attribute `pointer` of the `PyPerson` class is a pointer to a `Person` object, I thought that I could get the object at the adress pointed by `*pointer` with the syntax `*(PyPersonObject.pointer)`. However when I try to compile it I get the following error

```
 def set_parent(self, PyPerson father):
    cdef Person new_father=*(father.pointer)
                             ^
------------------------------------------------------------

person.pyx:51:30: Cannot assign type 'Person *' to 'Person'
```

Does someone knows how can I get to the object at the adress of the pointer? 
When I do the same in a C++ program I get no error. Here's the implementation of the C++ class in case you want to see it :

**person.cpp**

```
Person::Person():parent(NULL){
}

Person::setParent(Person &p){
     parent=&p;
}
```

NOTE: I can't solve it by holding a `Person` instance (`cdef Peron not_pointer`) for other reasons involving the complete class.

Answer (score 14, accepted):

I should have read the entire cython docs on using C++ with Cython. For those who don't know, the dereference operator`*` can't be used in Cython. Instead you need to import `dereference` from the `cython.operator` module. When you want to access the object at the pointed address, you should write `dereference(pointer)`.

In concrete, the answer to my problem is to write `cdef Person new_father=dereference(father.c_person)`.

Comment: tks, the issue troubled me about *this

Answer (score 5):

One another solution to this might be to index into the pointer at location **`0`** to dereference a pointer in Cython.
For example, suppose we have a golden_ratio C double and a p_double C pointer:

```
cdef double golden_ratio
cdef double *p_double
```

We can assign `golden_ratio’s` address to `p_double` using the address-of operator, &:

```
p_double = &golden_ratio
```

We can now assign to `golden_ratio` through `p_double` using our
**indexing-at-zero-to-dereference** syntax:

```
p_double[0] = 1.618
print(golden_ratio)
# => 1.618
```