# How to use void pointers in Cython

Tags: python, c, cython

I'm trying to use `void` pointers in `Cython`, and I can't figure out how to use them.
In `C` I can do this:

```
#include <stdio.h>
int n = 5;
void* ptr = &n;
printf("%d", *(int*)ptr);
```

And to convert it to `Cython` I tried using both:

```
from libc.stdio cimport printf
cdef int n = 5
cdef void* ptr = &n
printf("%d", (<int*>ptr))
```

and

```
printf("%d", *(<int*>ptr))
```

Any suggestions?

### Edit

I was able to solve it both by using John Bollingers' answer and by using:

```py
from cython.operator cimport dereference
from libc.stdio cimport printf
cdef int n = 5
cdef void* ptr = &n
printf("%d", dereference(<int*>ptr))
```

Comment: I think [this answer](https://stackoverflow.com/a/42577804/4657412) probably gives what you're asking.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Unlike C, [Cython does not have a unary `*` operator](https://cython.readthedocs.io/en/latest/src/userguide/language_basics.html#differences-between-c-and-cython-expressions).  Use array notation to dereference pointers:

```
from libc.stdio cimport printf
cdef int n = 5
cdef void *ptr = &n
printf("%d", (<int*>ptr)[0])
```